# Getting result starting from 15 minutes interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I have an SQL problem, I am getting the result but what I wanted is to get the starting 15 mins as well.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%h') AS CHAR(2)), ':',  
CAST(DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%m') AS CHAR(2))) timer, 
COUNT(*) ctrRes from tbl1 WHERE id = 1 AND cat = 2
GROUP BY ( 3 * HOUR( date_added ) + FLOOR( MINUTE( date_added ) / 15 ))
```

Sample result:

timer | ctrRes

01:28 |  1

01:44 | 22

02:14 | 253

02:29 | 238

Is there a way to get the record starting from 00:15 regardless of empty results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a record to be returned whether or not something is in that time slot. Well, there must be something there for MySQL to return. SQL is used to retrieve data, not to generate data, so if data does not exist, you can't get it. Hence, you need some way to create the data so that you can retrieve it.

You can either create this data temporarily upon every query, or you can materialize the data in an actual table. If you will run this query often, I would recommend that you materialize the data. There's an example on creating days at: https://gist.github.com/johngrimes/408559 You can customize it to generate times instead of dates.

Then the result becomes something like:

```
select * from TimeTable left join tbl1 on ... where <some range criteria>
```